# adduser hangs after calling it via ssh

Tags: ssh

I am trying to create a new user on a server using ssh like this:

`ssh root@myserver 'adduser newuser'`

It runs successfully, but ssh does not stops and hangs until I hit Ctrl+C.
What can I do with this?

Comment: Is it that `adduser` may be interactive and thus waits for input?

Comment: It could, but, to be honest, I don't know how to manage with that anyway

Comment: It might be possible to execute `adduser` so, that it doesn't wait for input, thus exiting and closing your SSH session.

Answer (score 0):

The `adduser` is interactive and for that TTY is needed. Run the `ssh` command with `-t` switch to make sure TTY is allocated on server:

```
ssh -t root@myserver 'adduser newuser'
```